# Custom Forms and User Groups

Tags: 2010

I am using SharePoint 2010 Standard Edition so not using InfoPath and Forms library..I want to create a list and create a form using designer and attach a workflow with it. The idea is that we have ID creation form based on different section let's say 3 sections and every section belongs to a group for filling and approval.

So what is the best strategy according to sharepoint to manage the groups...Should I create groups in SharePoint and add users accordingly and use javascript in NewForm, EditForm and DisplayForm to get current user group and disable the section which they are not allowed to fill in?

Please suggest how should I handle it in professional way and what is the best practice. Also keep one thing in mind that we have almost 10 departments and each departments will have 10 to 16 forms in similar way so based on that what should be my strategy.

Answer (score 1):

to resolve this issue I prefer to deploy an application page.

Anyway you can use Client OM / EMACScript to get the current user:

```
var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var currentweb = currentcontext.get_web();
currentcontext.load(currentweb);
var currentuser = currentweb.get_currentUser();
currentcontext.load(currentuser);
var loginName = currentuser.get_loginName();
```

off course you can get the user's groups too.

With the variable that contains groups you will show/hide the section of forms
do you want through jquery.